# Why is @override annotation optional?

Tags: dart

I understand definition of an [@override](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.17.1/dart-core/override-constant.html) annotation.

But, why is the usage of the annotation optional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The annotation wasn't made part of the language because the language designers didn't want to enforce its use.

It has been added as an optional annotation for people who want the feature, but it's only recognized by the analyzer tool, it's not actually part of the language.

Comment: So... they made it optional because they didn't want it to be required? I'm sure it wasn't intended this way, but this seems particularly unhelpful.

Comment: It was made optional because they didn't want it as part of the language. Dart doesn't require you to write anything to override a method. So really, it's not *optional*, it's *not there at all* from the language perspective. Some people do want the feature, even if the language doesn't have it, and they added the `@override` annotation and analyzer support. The annotation should really be in `package:meta` with other analyzer-recognized annotations instead of being in the platform libraries, and maybe we'll eventually move it there.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.17.1/dart-core/override-constant.html):

> The intent of the @override notation is to catch situations where a superclass renames a member, and an independent subclass which used to override the member, could silently continue working using the superclass implementation.

You might want to name your method equal to the super class without explicitely overriding it. This is allowed as it does not break any constraints.
Basically you can name your methods whatever you want.

`@Override` only enforces, that one of your parents has to have a method with the same signature.

Comment: Thank you! After a bunch of searching this is the first time I've found an explanation that actually helped! (apparently, I glossed over it when I read the official docs)

Answer (score 6):

You can enable a linter rule to enforce it

- http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/annotate_overrides.html

by adding an `.analysis_options` file to your project besides the `pubspec.yaml` file with this content

```
linter:
  rules:
    - annotate_overrides
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the name of the method is looked up in the inheritance chain: for example, let's look at this inheritance chain:

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

if we create an instance using class C and invoke a method test(), then the definition of test is first looked in the body of class C, then class B, then class A. Thus, the overriding effect is automatically implied.
The effect is similar to what observed in C++, and for a detailed read please check out this link:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

The reason of the existence of the annotation is clearly stated above by Abaddon666.